# Install grpcio via pip: "legacy-install-failure"

Tags: python, django, pip, grpcio

I want to install grpcio with pip(version 1.35).
But I get this error:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> grpcio
```

I tried to install python-dev or wheel, but it did not work.

My python version = 3.10

Ubuntu = 22.04

Comment: Can you try update your pip? eg. `python -m pip -U pip`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. Increase the version of grcpio helps me. Version 1.46.3 installed without any problem